# ZSH autocomplete option parsing: Accessing the completed value

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion

I have an autocompletion script, with this snippet:

```
_arguments \
  '-project[project file]:project:->projects'

...

case "$state" in
...
  projects)
    local -a projects
    projects=(*.project)
    _multi_parts / projects
    echo "$SELECTED_PROJECT" > /tmp/project
    ;;
...
```

How can I get access to the user-selected option from `_multi_parts / projects` such that there is a variable `$SELECTED_PROJECT` that is accessible to other parts of the completion script?

I have other options in the `_arguments` declaration that are dependent on which `project` the user has selected, but I can't seem to find a way to get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a completion function, the words that are already present on the command line are available [in the `$words` array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-words).

You can find examples of using `$words` with `_arguments` [in the completion functions that ship with Zsh](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/search?q=_arguments+words).